# jQuery Ajax object dot notation undefined from REST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

Hey guys I am having a really big problem understanding why my for each is unable to parse my REStful end point within my AJAX success function:

So I have the following code:

```js
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: '/showroom-event-gallery-api',
  success: function(data) {
    var rawData = data.slice(0,10);
    console.log(rawData);
    for (var i = 0, len = rawData.length; i < len; i++) {
      var imageName = rawData.name;
      console.log(imageName);
    }
  }
});
```

The `console.log(rawData);` statement runs successfully and shows the objects from my REST api. The issue that I am having is when I try and use dot notation to select a parameter called `name` within all of the objects and store them into a variable.

When I `console.log(imageName);` I get undefined however the name parameter is inside the object so I am unsure why this is happening?

Here is an example of my data:

```
[  
    {  
       id:225,
       car_image_category_id:37,
       image_name:"DSC_9672",
       name:"77a3b8f84d63557d165f3b4ecf0d079e5cd1ae67.jpg",
       path:"img/imagedb/77a3b8f84d63557d165f3b4ecf0d079e5cd1ae67.jpg",
       thumbnail_path:"img/imagedb/thumbs/tn-77a3b8f84d63557d165f3b4ecf0d079e5cd1ae67.jpg",
       created_at:"2016-07-27 18:13:50",
       updated_at:"2016-07-27 18:13:50"
    },
    {  
       id:226,
       car_image_category_id:37,
       image_name:"DSC_9673",
       name:"af508985a53d7288d58cea118389a58b3567b364.jpg",
       path:"img/imagedb/af508985a53d7288d58cea118389a58b3567b364.jpg",
       thumbnail_path:"img/imagedb/thumbs/tn-af508985a53d7288d58cea118389a58b3567b364.jpg",
       created_at:"2016-07-27 18:13:50",
       updated_at:"2016-07-27 18:13:50"
    },
    {  
       id:227,
       car_image_category_id:37,
       image_name:"DSC_9677",
       name:"85832b6a6d952873f2e277ca19b5eab826d63340.jpg",
       path:"img/imagedb/85832b6a6d952873f2e277ca19b5eab826d63340.jpg",
       thumbnail_path:"img/imagedb/thumbs/tn-85832b6a6d952873f2e277ca19b5eab826d63340.jpg",
       created_at:"2016-07-27 18:13:51",
       updated_at:"2016-07-27 18:13:51"
    }
 ]
```

As you can see `name` is available to be selected however when I use dot notation to do this my variable comes back as undefined.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `rawData[i].name`

```
   for (var i = 0, len = rawData.length; i < len; i++) {
      var imageName = rawData[i].name;
      console.log(imageName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to Replace

```
var imageName = rawData.name;
```

with

```
var imageName = rawData[i].name;
```

You are now trying to get the name of an array and not the object

Answer (score 0):

`$.each()` function is much easy to use with array try this.

```
$.each(rawData, function( index, value ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + value );
});
```